# Is there a smart solution to fix the precision issue for atan?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\psset{unit=.25}
\def\Atom#1{%
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](-12,-12)(12,12)
    \pstVerb{/AA 1 5 atan def /RR 26 sqrt def}
    \pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=red,linearc=#1]
    {
            \pscircle{3}
            \moveto(5,-1)
            \psLoop{6}
            {
                    \translate(5,0)
                    \psline(0,-1)(4,-1)(4,1)(0,1)
                    \translate(-5,0)
                    \psarc(0,0){!RR}{!AA}{!60 AA sub}
                    \rotate{60}
            }
            \closepath
    }
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\Atom{.5}
\Atom{0}
\end{document}
```

What causes the strange output for nonzero `linearc` below?

### Output for `linearc=.5`

[image]

### Output for `linearc=0`

[image]

### Edit

According to Werner's comment, it is related to precision issue. Is there a smart solution to solve it?

Comment: My guess is this has to do with the precision of `1 5 atan`...

Comment: @Werner Yes, you are right. Using `/AA 1 1e-6 add 5 atan def` eliminates this last, big arc, but others become more visible.

Comment: Can a bounty of 1 million make this problem solved?

Comment: Maybe. Wouldn't it be my part then? :)

Comment: I do not dare to take this kind of commitment. :-)

Comment: Could you adapt a solution like the in tikz one to avoid using atan ? even without trigonometry for small angles. See edited answer (I uderstand it's not exactly the question you ask).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the current path have a point (`\moveto`, previous `\psarc`), then `\psline` 
also draw a line from the current point to its first coordinate. In theory both points are identical. However these points are calculated completely different, the end point of `\psarc` and the first point of `\psline` rotated by `\rotate{60}`. Therefore rounding errors cannot be avoided in practice. The result is a very tiny line, much smaller than the arc that `linearc` wants to draw.

**Solution:** Just drop the redundant point, the first point of `\psline`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\psset{unit=.25}
\def\Atom#1{%
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](-12,-12)(12,12)
    \pstVerb{/AA 1 5 atan def /RR 26 sqrt def}
    \pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=red,linearc=#1]
    {
            \pscircle{3}
            \moveto(5,-1)
            \psLoop{6}
            {
                    \translate(5,0)
                    \psline(4,-1)(4,1)(0,1)
                    \translate(-5,0)
                    \psarc(0,0){!RR}{!AA}{!60 AA sub}
                    \rotate{60}
            }
            \closepath
    }
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\Atom{.5}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Drawing without `atan`, just a `sin` and even without trigonometry for small angles up to 12° (24 infact) without difference, example with 15° and a little gap.
Drawing is done in one path.

1. in pale red the exact solution;
2. in blue the without trigo.

**For 10° :**

[image]

zoom :

[image]

**For 15° (small gap) :**

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\def\Rex{5}
\def\Rin{3}
\def\Theeth{2}
\def\Angle{10}
\def\R{.3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Lt{2*sin(\Angle)*\Rex}
\pgfmathsetmacro\L{2*\Rex*\Angle*3.14159/180}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%\clip (-5,2) rectangle (0,7) ;

% exact solution
% with trigonometry but whithout atan, just a sin
% in red

\fill[fill=red!25,,even odd rule]  (-\Angle:\Rex)
\foreach \i in {0,60,...,300} {
    --(-\Angle+\i:\Rex)
    --++(\i:\Theeth-\R) arc (-90+\i:0+\i:\R)
    --++(90+\i:\Lt-2*\R) arc (0+\i:90+\i:\R)
    --(\Angle+\i:\Rex) arc (\Angle+\i:60-\Angle+\i:\Rex)
} -- cycle (0,0) circle (\Rin);

% approximative solution without trigonometry
% if x is small sin(x) ~ x in radian

\draw[blue] (0,0) circle (\Rin) (-\Angle:\Rex)
\foreach \i in {0,60,...,300} {
    --(-\Angle+\i:\Rex)
    --++(\i:\Theeth-\R) arc (-90+\i:0+\i:\R)
    --++(90+\i:\L-2*\R) arc (0+\i:90+\i:\R)
    --(\Angle+\i:\Rex) arc (\Angle+\i:60-\Angle+\i:\Rex)
} -- cycle ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```